# Copy content inside HTML <dl> into a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, I want to copy the dl id content into the result field but i cant get it to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#result').text())
  $('.result').val($('#result').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="results">
<dl id="content">
  content to be copy
</dl>
```

Comment: What does `$('#result')` mean? Element with `id="result"`. There's no such thing. VTC for typo.

Answer (score 0):

You have class with `results` not `id`. To grab the `dl` use `$('#content')` or `$('dl')`.

```js
const text = $('#content').text();
$('.results').val(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="results">
<dl id="content">
  content to be copy
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct class name and Id name. Working example https://jsfiddle.net/Rakesh029/kjern1w9/8/

```
 $('.results').val($('#content').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you try to refer the result id which is not exists into your code. Also, you try to set the value to "result" class. Your code has class name "results".

You may get the text value of dl tag like:

```
var result = $('#content').text();
```

Set result value to input tag like:

```
$('.results').val(result );
```

Here, "results" will be the class of your input tag.